# Giving output of an array received from a function in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, vbscript

I am trying to present the output of the array which I have received from a VBScript function in the XML tags via XSLT. But the file structure is not just correct.

Here is the XSLT code :

```
<PID25>
<xsl:variable name='var:vRaceArray' select='userVBScript:readfile(string(DEMOGRAPHICS/DEM_RACE/text()))'/>
<xsl:for-each select="$var:vRaceArray">
<PID25.1>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<PID25.1>
</xsl:for-each>
</PID25>
```

The VBscript code is as :

```
Function readfile(p_String1)

Set userArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
StrRace = p_String1
For i = 0 To Len(p_String1)
Do 
    p_String1 = Mid(StrRace, i + 1, 1)
    If p_String1 = 0 Then
    'GoTo Now
    End If

'MsgBox (p_String1)
If Trim(p_String1) = "0" Then
        fctSelectRaceDes = ""
    ElseIf Trim(p_String1) = "1" Then
        fctSelectRaceDes = "American Indian or Alaska Native"
    ElseIf Trim(p_String1) = "2" Then
        fctSelectRaceDes = "Asian"
    ElseIf Trim(p_String1) = "3" Then
        fctSelectRaceDes = "Black or African-American"
    ElseIf Trim(p_String1) = "4" Then
        fctSelectRaceDes = "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander"
    ElseIf Trim(p_String1) = "5" Then
        fctSelectRaceDes = "White"
    ElseIf Trim(p_String1) = "6" Then
        fctSelectRaceDes = ""
    ElseIf Trim(p_String1) = "7" Then
        fctSelectRaceDes = "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander"
    ElseIf Trim(p_String1) = "8" Then
        fctSelectRaceDes = "Other Race"
End If
'MsgBox (fctSelectRaceDesc)
'ArrayRace(i) = fctSelectRaceDesc
'MsgBox (ArrayRace(i))
userArrayList.Add fctSelectRaceDes

Loop While False
i = i + 1
Next



Set readfile = userArrayList
End Function
```

Anyone can please provide a solution to this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the file structure is not correct"? Showing you current output, and the output you actually expect would probably help a lot here. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC Hi Tim, my input to the function would be '1,2', so the output which I would be expecting would be
<PID25.1>American Indian or Alaska Native<PID25.1>
<PID25.1>Asian<PID25.1>

Comment: @TimC I also received the error like-
Transform Init Errors:
Function 'readfile' did not return a value , or it returned a value that cannot be converted to an XSL data type.

Comment: Are you sure you need to implement that function with VB or VBScript? It looks like you should be able to split the string with the numbers and map those numbers to the strings with pure XSLT. As for using VBScript, which XSLT processor do you use exactly? If you want to pass around structured data between XSLT and extension functions then you need to look at the documentation of your XSLT processor, for instance for `XslCompiledTransform` the document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx lists the types that can be passed around in a table.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: @RamMehta, if you describe the input format you have and tell us which result you want we hopefully can help with the XSLT code. If you simply need to break up a string with e.g. `1,2,4` into the numbers `1`, `2`, `4` and then map each number to a string then that is surely doable in pure XSLT. Most tasks in XSLT 1.0 however are easier using an extension function like `exsl:node-set` so make sure you tell us exactly which XSLT processor.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am willing to do the same as you have mentioned.
I would have the input as 1,2,4 and then I would be mapping them to the values as they arein the VBScript function. A array would be created in the VBScript, and the same is returned to me in the XSLT.
I have this : xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt'& version='1.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it with plain XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:data="http://example.com/data"
  exclude-result-prefixes="data">

<xsl:param name="wrap-name" select="'PID25.1'"/>

<data:data xmlns="">
  <code number="1">American Indian or Alaska Native</code>
  <code number="2">Asian</code>
  <code number="3">Black or African-American</code>
  <code number="4">Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander</code>
  <code number="5">White</code>
  <code number="6"></code>
  <code number="7">Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander</code>
  <code number="8">Other Race</code>
</data:data>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="race" match="code" use="@number"/>

<xsl:variable name="stylesheet" select="document('')"/>

<xsl:template name="map">
  <xsl:param name="code"/>
  <xsl:param name="wrap" select="$wrap-name"/>
  <xsl:if test="$code != '0'">
    <xsl:for-each select="$stylesheet">
      <xsl:element name="{$wrap}">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('race', $code)"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="wrap-tokens">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:param name="sep" select="','"/>
  <xsl:param name="name" select="$wrap-name"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(contains($string, $sep))">
      <xsl:call-template name="map">
        <xsl:with-param name="code" select="$string"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="wrap" select="$name"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="map">
        <xsl:with-param name="code" select="substring-before($string, $sep)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="wrap" select="$name"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="wrap-tokens">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $sep)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="sep" select="$sep"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DEM_RACE">
  <xsl:call-template name="wrap-tokens">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms `<DEM_RACE>0,1,2,5,6,8</DEM_RACE>` into

```
<PID25.1>American Indian or Alaska Native</PID25.1>
<PID25.1>Asian</PID25.1>
<PID25.1>White</PID25.1>
<PID25.1/>
<PID25.1>Other Race</PID25.1>
```

Comment: Did you check that somewhere on an Online XSLT Transformer ?

Comment: @RamMehta, I wrote that code and tested with an XSLT 1.0 processor like Saxon 6. If you are using XslCompiledTransform then you need to make sure you use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltsettings.enabledocumentfunction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: @MartinHonen, thanks the file is working, but I want that when input is zero, it should goto the next number. What changes should I make to the code ?

Comment: I dont want a blank <PID25.1> coming up for zero, or rather we can say I just dont want the <PID25.1> coming for that.

Comment: @RamMehta, what about `6`, what should be output when that number is found?

Comment: @MartinHonen That can be be blank , that's  a valid one.

Comment: @RamMehta, I have edited the answer to make sure `0` does not create an element.